How to create a simple Recurring Event?
I have to create a class EvenimentRecurent which is a subclass of class Eveniment which is looking like this:
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Eveniment {

  private Date dataInceput, dataSfarsit;
  private String nume;

  public Eveniment(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
      this.dataInceput = format.parse(dataInceput);
      this.dataSfarsit = format.parse(dataSfarsit);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Data nu este in formatul cerut!");
    }
    this.nume = nume;
  }

  public Date getDataInceput() {
    return dataInceput;
  }

  public Date getDataSfarsit() {
    return dataSfarsit;
  }

  public String getNume() {
    return nume;
  }
}

Class "EvenimentRecurent" has to contain a public method urmatorulEveniment that get as parameter a String in this format yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss and return a String with the next event in the same format.
This class also contain a Constructor EvenimentRecurent(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume, int numarOre), and an int numarOre
For example:
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

class Eveniment {

    private Date dataInceput, dataSfarsit;
    private String nume;

    public Eveniment(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.dataInceput = format.parse(dataInceput);
            this.dataSfarsit = format.parse(dataSfarsit);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data nu este in formatul cerut!");
        }

        this.nume = nume;
    }

    public Date getDataInceput() {
        return dataInceput;
    }

    public Date getDataSfarsit() {
        return dataSfarsit;
    }

    public String getNume() {
        return nume;
    }
}

class EvenimentRecurent extends Eveniment {

    private Date dataP;
    private int numarOre;

    public EvenimentRecurent(String dataInceput, String dataSfarsit, String nume, int numarOre) {
        super(dataInceput, dataSfarsit, nume);
        this.numarOre = numarOre;
    }

    public String urmatorulEveniment(String dataP) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            this.dataP = format.parse(dataP);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Data nu este in formatul cerut!");
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(this.dataP);
        c.add(Calendar.HOUR, numarOre);
        String urmatorulEveniment = format.format(c.getTime());
        return urmatorulEveniment;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EvenimentRecurent er = new EvenimentRecurent("2019-03-09 22:46:00",
                "2019-03-09 23:00:00", "Informatics", 24);
        System.out.println(er.urmatorulEveniment("2019-04-19 22:46:23")); // Here i should get "2019-04-20 22:46:00"
    }
}


You have shown us your code. Now what's the actual question/Which part of that code is the problem and why? Also, I would recommend using java.time classes instead of Date and Calendar.

I don't get it. Why do you think you should get "2019-04-20 22:46:00" instead of "2019-04-20 22:46:23"?

Translating to English may get you better responses here. This edition of Stack Overflow is English-only.

Are you trying to assign a different time-of-day to your date? If so, say so. Your Question as written is confusing.

Your Question is confusing, seemingly unfocused. But I can make two core points: java.time and ISO 8601.
Never use Calendar nor SimpleDateFormat. These terribly flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
Your input is nearly compliant with the ISO 8601 standard used by default in java.time for generating/parsing text. To fully comply, simple replace the SPACE character in the middle with a T.
String input = "2019-04-19 22:46:23".replace( " " , "T" ) ;

Parse your date-with-time as a LocalDateTime object.
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;

Be aware that a mere date with time-of-day is inherently ambiguous. We cannot know if your input means 10 PM in Tokyo Japan, 10 PM in Toulouse France, or 10 PM in Toledo Ohio US — three different moments several hours apart.
For the same reason, the Calendar, even if we ignore its flaws, is not fit for your purpose. A Calendar object represents a moment, a particular point on the timeline. A date-with-time is not a moment, is not a point on the timeline.
Your Question seems to want to assign a different time-of-day to the input value. If so, use LocalTime class.
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 ) ;  // Noon: 12:00:00.
LocalDateTime ldtNoon = ldt.with( lt ) ;

Be aware that use of the ambiguous LocalDateTime class means you will not account for temporal anomalies imposed by politicians in a time zone. For example, on the cutover day of Daylight Saving Time (DST), there may not be a noon hour in your intended time zone, or there may be two noon hours. The code above will be blissfully unaware of such issues.
